How can I assign different colors and styles to the corresponding bars of two sets of data in DiscretePlot3D?
How can I assign different colors and styles to the corresponding bars of two sets of data in DiscretePlot3D?
In the current graph, they are all magenta. For example, I would like them to use different RGB colors. How should I set this up?
How can I assign different colors and styles to the corresponding bars of two sets of data in DiscretePlot3D?
In the current graph, they are all magenta. For example, I would like them to use different RGB colors. How should I set this up?
Crosstalkx = {{0.01, 0.002137962, 0.016218101, 0.000870964, 
   0.005623413, 0.03801894, 1},
  {0.011220185, 0.020417379, 0.016595869, 0.001318257, 0.001479108, 1,
    0.005495409},
  {0.001348963, 0.000812831, 0.000446684, 0.000323594, 1, 0.001258925,
    0.000123027},
  {0.003090295, 0.003467369, 0.001513561, 1, 0.005128614, 0.001071519,
    0.000263027},
  {0.00020893, 0.000186209, 1, 0.000213796, 0.00042658, 0.00128825, 
   0.00616595},
  {0.007762471, 1, 0.011481536, 0.001174898, 0.003162278, 0.019054607,
    0.003715352},
  {1, 0.033113112, 0.004365158, 0.000776247, 0.00676083, 0.005754399, 
   0.002344229}
  }

Crosstalky = {{0.01, 0.002137962, 0.016218101, 0.000870964, 
   0.005623413, 0.03801894, 1},
  {0.011220185, 0.020417379, 0.016595869, 0.001318257, 0.001479108, 1,
    0.005495409},
  {0.001348963, 0.000812831, 0.000446684, 0.000323594, 1, 0.001258925,
    0.000123027},
  {0.003090295, 0.003467369, 0.001513561, 1, 0.005128614, 0.001071519,
    0.000263027},
  {0.00020893, 0.000186209, 1, 0.000213796, 0.00042658, 0.00128825, 
   0.00616595},
  {0.007762471, 1, 0.011481536, 0.001174898, 0.003162278, 0.019054607,
    0.003715352},
  {1, 0.033113112, 0.004365158, 0.000776247, 0.00676083, 0.005754399, 
   0.002344229}
  }

(*colorSettings={{0.,CMYKColor[.508,.204,.045,.28]},{0.2,CMYKColor[.1,\
.4,0,.28]},{0.5,CMYKColor[.509,.4028,0,.28]}}*)
colorSettings = {{0., CMYKColor[.18, .39, .045, .28]}, {0.2, 
   CMYKColor[.1, .4, 0, .28]}, {0.5, CMYKColor[.32, .39, 0, .28]}}

myPlot = 
 DiscretePlot3D[{Crosstalkx[[Mass - 1/8, Radius]], 
   Crosstalky[[Mass + 1/8, Radius]]}, {Mass, -1/2, 15/2, 
   1/8}, {Radius, 1, 7},
  (*Mass是x轴 两个分别向左右各偏移1/8，而Radius是y轴，不需要偏移*)
  (*{Crosstalkx[[Mass-1/8,Radius]],Crosstalky[[Mass+1/8,
  Radius]]},{Mass,-1/2,30/4,1/8},{Radius,1,7},*)
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[colorSettings, #3] &),
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True, ExtentSize -> 0.25,
  ExtentElementFunction -> "PlaneFadingCube",
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Opacity[0.8, White], 
    EdgeForm[{RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Thickness[0.002]}]],
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.618*0.3},
  ImagePadding -> {{30, 20}, {30, 20}},
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
  PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 1.2}},
  AxesLabel -> {Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black],
    Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black],
    Rotate[Style["Normalized Crosstalk", 12, Bold, Black], 3.14/2]}, 
  Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {0, 0.25, 
     0.5, 0.75, 1}},
  TicksStyle -> {{12, Bold}, {12, Bold}, {12, Bold}},
  PlotLabel -> "Crosstalk between different Modes",
  ImageSize -> 700,
  ScalingFunctions -> "Linear",
  Boxed -> False, BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]] ]



Delete the "ColorFunction" specification and "White" in the "PlotStyle":
DiscretePlot3D[{Crosstalkx[[Mass - 1/8, Radius]], 
  Crosstalky[[Mass + 1/8, Radius]]}, {Mass, -1/2, 15/2, 1/8}, {Radius,
   1, 7}, ExtentSize -> 0.25, 
 ExtentElementFunction -> "PlaneFadingCube", 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Opacity[0.8], 
   EdgeForm[{RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Thickness[0.002]}]], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.618*0.3}, ImagePadding -> {{30, 20}, {30, 20}},
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 1.2}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black], 
   Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black], 
   Rotate[Style["Normalized Crosstalk", 12, Bold, Black], 3.14/2]}, 
 Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {0, 0.25, 
    0.5, 0.75, 1}}, 
 TicksStyle -> {{12, Bold}, {12, Bold}, {12, Bold}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Crosstalk between different Modes", ImageSize -> 700, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Linear", Boxed -> False, 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]]]


Addendum
To specify different colors for different datasets, you need to specify several "PlotStyle":
DiscretePlot3D[{Crosstalkx[[Mass - 1/8, Radius]], 
  Crosstalky[[Mass + 1/8, Radius]]}, {Mass, -1/2, 15/2, 1/8}, {Radius,
   1, 7}, ExtentSize -> 0.25, 
 ExtentElementFunction -> "PlaneFadingCube", 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, Opacity[0.8], 
    EdgeForm[{RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Thickness[0.002]}]], 
   Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.8], 
    EdgeForm[{RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Thickness[0.002]}]]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.618*0.3}, ImagePadding -> {{30, 20}, {30, 20}},
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 1.2}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black], 
   Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black], 
   Rotate[Style["Normalized Crosstalk", 12, Bold, Black], 3.14/2]}, 
 Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {0, 0.25, 
    0.5, 0.75, 1}}, 
 TicksStyle -> {{12, Bold}, {12, Bold}, {12, Bold}}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Crosstalk between different Modes", ImageSize -> 700, 
 ScalingFunctions -> "Linear", Boxed -> False, 
 BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]]]



Thanks you very much！

But what shall i do if i want to set a spectific color

now its the default color

To specify different colors for different datasets, you need to specify several "PlotStyle", see my answer.

Thanks you very much !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
